# Write docker logs to external log file

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

We have a number of nodejs based microservices and all of them are running as docker containers.

Below is the content of dockerfile:

```
FROM keymetrics/pm2-docker-alpine:latest

ARG ENVIRONMENT
ARG PORT

ENV PORT $PORT
ENV ENVIRONMENT $ENVIRONMENT

RUN apt-get update -qq


RUN apt-get install --yes curl
RUN curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install --yes nodejs
RUN apt-get install --yes build-essential vim


RUN mkdir /database_service
ADD . /database_service
WORKDIR /database_service

RUN npm install -g path
RUN npm cache clean

EXPOSE $PORT

CMD [ "npm", "start", $PORT, $ENVIRONMENT ]
```

Below is the command used to run the container

```
sudo docker run -p ${EXTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER}:${INTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER} --network 
${NETWORK} --name ${SERVICE_NAME} --restart always -m 2048M --memory-swap -1 
-itd ${ORGANISATION}/${SERVICE_NAME}:${VERSION}
```

I am looking for a way write contents of the logs generated by docker node based service to the external file on the Linux VM machine. If someone can help with sample command that will help.

Comment: Possibly the documentation on [logging drivers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/) would be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
sudo docker run -p ${EXTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER}:${INTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER} --network 
${NETWORK} --name ${SERVICE_NAME} --restart always -m 2048M --memory-swap -1 
-itd ${ORGANISATION}/${SERVICE_NAME}:${VERSION} > /path/to/your/log.txt
```

Comment: I am also looking solution for the same problem statement. The command you mention creating the `log.txt` but it contains only Docker container Id.How can I have the complete log for the container?